# Vue form not submitting

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, frameworks, axios

I'm trying to submit a form with data in order to get an API key that I need to use to fetch the API data. I made a form in Vue.js, however, it's not submitting my form. I'm a beginner when it comes to Vue so i have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate some help.

My App.vue:

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
   <Login @loginformdata="submitlogin"/>
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 import Login from './components/Login.vue';
 import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
 import axios from 'axios';


 export default {
   name: 'app',
   data()
   {
     return {
       errors: [],
       logins: []
   }
 },
 components: {
   Login
 },
 methods: {
   submitlogin(credentials){
   const {personeelsnummer, wachtwoord } = credentials;

   axios.post('http://localhost/api/apikey/', {
     personeelsnummer,
     wachtwoord
   })
   .then(res => this.logins)
   .catch(e => {
     this.errors.push(e)
   })
}
}
}
</script>
```

My Login.vue:

```
 <template>
<div @submit="logintest">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input v-model="personeelsnummer" type="text" name="personeelsnummer" placeholder="personeelsnummer">&nbsp;
    <input v-model="wachtwoord" type="password" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="wachtwoord">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "Login",
data() {
    return {
        personeelsnummer: '',
        wachtwoord: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    logintest(p, w){
        alert('test');
        const login = {
            personeelsnummer: this.personeelsnummer,
            wachtwoord: this.wachtwoord
        }
        //Send to parent
        this.$emit('loginformdata', login);
    }
}
 }
  </script>
```

Comment: Remove submit from `<div @submit="logintest">`, and add click event `<input @click="logintest" value="Submit">`.

Comment: Or use `<form @submit.prevent="loigntest">` instead of `<div @submit="logintest">`.

Comment: `<div @submit>` LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding a `submit` handler on a `div` which will never work since this element does not have that event in the first place. What you could (and probably should) do is add all these input fields on a `form` which does have a [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) event.

```vue
<form @submit="logintest">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <input v-model="personeelsnummer" type="text" name="personeelsnummer" placeholder="personeelsnummer">&nbsp;
  <input v-model="wachtwoord" type="password" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="wachtwoord">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Also, passing data with Ajax requests can get tedious especially when you have massive amount of input fields to serialize and send along with the request, so I would recommend [`form-serialize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-serialize) for this. It supports two output formats, URL-encoded (default) or hash (JS objects).

```vue
<div id="app">
  <form @submit="logintest" ref="form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="personeelsnummer">&nbsp;
    <input type="password" name="wachtwoord">

    <!-- Imagine 10 more fields in here -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import serialize from 'form-serialize';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    logintest() {
      // Outputs { personeelsnummer: value, wachtwoord: value }
      let data = serialize(this.$refs.form, {
        hash: true
      });

      // Do something with data here
    }
  }
})
```